# Recommend me a widely used web-based file sharing system

Tags: file-sharing

I need to choose and install a server-client platform for a ~150 user base. They should be able to upload files (after logging in) through a web form and browse folders, download whatever the other users have uploaded, etc. All files would be private, no public links are generated. Some basic admin tasks would be needed too (add users, delete files). It should run over PHP + MySQL since it's gonna be deployed in a basic, third-party hosting service.

I know that FTP would be the straightforward solution but something fancier is required. The team wouldn't mind paying for a license as long as we're getting a popular, solid product.

What's your recommendation?

Comment: you mean like office 365? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/small-business/about.aspx

Comment: Could be but I don't know since the description is not very detailed. I just joined the beta, I hope it's fine!

Comment: Why does it need to be a popular product? Wouldn't it make more sense to choose one based on features, rather than popularity?

Comment: I've noticed that some of the best-looking solutions are currently unmantained, or in any case they don't seem to have a solid team behind the development.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [filesender](http://www.filesender.org/) it is a new development for the academic (R&D) world, but it might suit your needs.

There is a feature list on its website which I will not repeat here. Take a look and decide if it is for you or not.

Answer (score 1):

[nephthys](http://oss.netshadow.at/wiki/nephthys)

seems also apropriate, it has nice features as well.

Comment: Was curious to see what that is, but the link to oss.netshadow.at is dead, and the domain itself seems to have not even DNS records of any kind.